# How to solve jquery conflict after loading data?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to load category wise data.I want to display this data by lightbox.I am giving my js code below:-

```
$(".ajaxLoad").click(function(event)
    {
        str=$(this).attr("href");
        signal="scripts/getPortfolio.php?id="+str;
        $.ajax({url:signal,
            beforeSend: function() {
              $("#indexSpinner").css("visibility","visible");
              },
              complete: function() {
                   $("#indexSpinner").css("visibility","hidden");
              },
            success:function(result){
            $(".hover").html(result);
        }});
         event.preventDefault();
    });
```

By this code I am successful to fetch data.But when I am trying to show this data into lightbox,its not showing data in lightbox.I am giving the full jquery code below :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a.group").fancybox({
      'nextEffect'  :   'fade',
      'prevEffect'  :   'fade',
      'overlayOpacity' :  0.8,
      'overlayColor' : '#000000',
      'arrows' : false,
      });           


    $(".ajaxLoad").click(function(event)
    {
        str=$(this).attr("href");
        signal="scripts/getPortfolio.php?id="+str;
        $.ajax({url:signal,
            beforeSend: function() {
              $("#indexSpinner").css("visibility","visible");
              },
              complete: function() {
                   $("#indexSpinner").css("visibility","hidden");
              },
            success:function(result){
            $(".hover").html(result);
        }});
         event.preventDefault();
    });

});
})(jQuery);
```

How Can I load data in lightbox.Any idea?

Comment: are you loading "a.group" with ajax?

Comment: Yes,But Its not working,I think Its jquery confliction @Reza Mamun

Comment: If it is conflicting, then you should see some errors in your Firefox console panel. Are you getting any?

Comment: I am not getting any error,Using jquery I am able to fetch data.But I am not able to display those data in lightbox.When I am clicking on data Its openining in a page but not in lightbox.This is my problem @Reza Mamun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs , there is a setting `'live': true` which is by default `true`, but you should add it;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //just put a dollar sign here to avoid jQuery confliction inside this scope;

    var fancySettings = {
        'live'        : true,
        'nextEffect'  : 'fade',
        'prevEffect'  : 'fade',
        'overlayOpacity' : 0.8,
        'overlayColor' : '#000000',
        'arrows' : false //, in the last key-value pair, here should not be any ',' otherwise it will create error, specially in IE and older browsers
    };

    //for initial items:
    $("a.group").fancybox(fancySettings);


    $(".ajaxLoad").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        str = $(this).attr("href");
        signal="scripts/getPortfolio.php?id="+str;
        $.ajax({
            url:signal,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#indexSpinner").css("visibility","visible");
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#indexSpinner").css("visibility","hidden");
            },
            success:function(result){
                $(".hover").html(result).find("a.group").fancybox(fancySettings); //define with each load for ajaxed items;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are running with older version of fancybox, then we should try in another way;

Comment: I have updated the success function and a little part above; you can try if you get any luck.